# Proving tight bound Θ for worst-case running time of an algorithm without proving lower bound Ω

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, proof-techniques

See this answer first: [Proving worst-case running time is in $\Omega(n^2)$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86422/proving-worst-case-running-time-is-in-omegan2)

Understanding the linked answer for insertion sort leads to the following statement. Prove that the statement is either incorrect or correct.

Statement:
If you find $(y)$ for worst case running time of an algorithm using some possible worst input. This finding is sufficient to now state $Θ(y)$ without demonstrating $Ω(y)$ for worst case running time of that algorithm.

Caution:

Using insertion sort as an example - Keep in mind that when you are finding the $y$ in $(y)$ using some sample input that you know is worst, you cannot come up with $y = 2^n$ because you would not get $y = 2^n$ for any input that you can think of sorting. The worst input that you can think of is an array sorted in opposite order which will get you $y = n^2$. Therefore, leads to conclusion that $O(n^2)$ for worst case running time of insertion sort.

This conclusion is also enough to conclude $Θ(n^2)$ for worst case running time of insertion sort if statement given above is true. Statement is general and stated for all algorithms, not just for insertion sort as demonstrated in this example.

Comment: I am failing to tag this user: https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/683/yuval-filmus

Comment: Please upvote my question so that I can earn reputation to comment. I can't earn reputation by giving helpful answers just yet as I am new to the topics discussed here.

Comment: You have to be a lot more specific about what you mean when you say 'you find $O(f(n))$ for worst case run time of an algorithm'. $O(f(n))$ isn't a value, or even a function; the 'most correct' way of interpreting $O(f(n))$ is as a _set_ of functions (namely, all the functions $g(n)$ such that there are constants $M$ and $N_0$ such that $g(n) \lt Mf(n)$ for all $n\gt N_0$). From this perspective saying that a function $g$ 'is' $O(f(n))$ is a little bit of an abuse of notation; what we should say is that $g()\in O(f(n))$; that is, that $g()$ is a member of that set.

Comment: The lower bound can be found by showing each input would run through each outer loop and each inner loop no matter what you do and it is indeed quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking exact definitions of asymptotic notations, to say informally: $\Omega(f(n))$ is set of functions that are lower bounded by $f(n)$, while $O(f(n))$ are set of functions upper bounded by $f(n)$, so when you have some example that runs in $O(n^2)$ it doesn't mean that it can't run in constant time, for example in $O(1)$, by $O$ you specify upper bound, not lower bound. I would suggest this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition.

P.S also I don't understand how the link you provided is connected to the question you asked, the question you linked is about why 1 example input for each n is enough for proving worst-case running time of insertion sort.

Comment: I am aware of the definitions. Few points -> 1: lets stick to insertion sort. 2: what insertion sort can do for non-worst case inputs (such as running in constant time) is irrelevant to the question. 3: to prove $Ω(n^2)$ we pick one such input of size n for which insertion sort runs in time that is function of $n^2$ and proof is done as per the linked answer. My question is why not just stick with the very worst example used to demonstrate $(^2)$ (input is array sorted in opposite order), this same example would also qualify for demonstrating $Ω(n^2)$ as per the rules of the linked answer.

Comment: where is $O(n^2)$ mentioned in the link you provided, also opposite of the sorted order can be one example to prove worst-case running time for each n. author of the answer clarified the idea of worst-case running time and the idea that 1 such example input is enough, which input he didn't specify and wasn't necessary to specify in that answer.

Comment: I think there is only one example that can be picked to prove $O(n^2)$ and that is array sorted in opposite order. I am picking that example now. What I am asking is does that same example suffice to prove $Ω(^2)$?

Comment: the fact that something runs in $O(n^2)$ doesn't mean that it runs in $\Omega(n^2)$ , take constant $f=O(1)$ for example which belongs to the first set but not the last one. in this case picking  example you mentioned would suffice to prove $\Omega(n^2)$ however proof details may be different, since $O(n^2)$ means being upper bounded, while the $\Omega$ denotes lower bound as I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: you keep bringing up other examples. we are specifically talking about worst case running time of insertion sort. I know that big O and big omega are used to denote different things. One is for upper bounds and other for lower bounds. I know that.

Comment: what I am trying to get at is that the answer in the link described such a way of proving big omega that it doesn't make sense to ever consider big omega for worst case running time. we should just stick with saying big theta once we find big O for worst case. big omega makes no sense once we say the words "worst case" if the explanation in the linked answer is true. Only saving grace would be if you tell me I can't use the example I used for proving $O(n^2)$ and that I must find an example with lower constants but with same order (such as 1/18 $n^2$, etc.) to prove big omega.

Comment: In that case, I will ask you how do I go about find such examples. There are many such examples, which one I choose. Answer linked will say choose any example, it doesn't matter. but problem is that I will keep finding tighter and tighter lower bounds. This whole process is arbitrary and re-kindles the opinion that attempt at finding example input for finding big omega is not useful once you utter the words "worst case"

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about anymore, question(on the link) specifically asked about $\Omega(n^2)$, what you're saying is that saying $\Omega(f(n))$  for worst-case analysis isn't important.  there is difference between saying some algorithm's  worst-case run is upper-bounded by $f(n)$ and  some algorithm's worst-case run is lower-bouned by $f(n)$.

Comment: the manner in which the linked answer asks to demonstrate lower bound by picking one worst case example, makes it useless to find lower bound f(n) because the order of such lower bound f(n) will always be the same as the order of f(n) found for big O. (for worst case running time that is)

Comment: in this example this may work, which also needs proof(however obvious it may be), but general case would also require proof that worst-case upper-bound and worst-case lower-bound is same(which doesn't seem correct), saying something in worst-case is upper-bounded by $O(f(n))$ doesn't mean that it is lower bounded by exactly same function, I would again suggest you to view definitions of asymptotic notations.

Comment: give me one example when "something in worst-case is upper-bounded by (()) doesn't mean that it is lower bounded by exactly same function". Saying worst case makes this false because if this statement was true then you simply put didn't choose worst case input. AND it won't be the same function f(n), but we are only concerned with the biggest term in that f(n) ignoring any constant of such big term.

Comment: for the same insertion-sort, I can say that worst-case is $O(2^n)$ (am I incorrect here formally?), also if the question boils down to the question that you commented at last, I would suggest editing the post and asking exactly that question.

Comment: formally correct as per definition of big O but once you are finding upper bound using worst case example, you will never get $2^n$, worst you can have is array sorted in opposite order which will get you most tight upper bound that is $O(n^2)$

Comment: I agree, but I gave counter-example, also it's not always easy for every algorithm to find tight bounds, so if the question is about that(finding whether worst case running time is upper-bounded and lower-bounded by the same function, which in fact is $\Theta$ definition) I would suggest to ask exactly that question.

Comment: If you find $O(f(n))$ for worst case running time of an algorithm using some possible worst input. Is this finding sufficient to state $Θ(f(n)$ without demonstrating $Ω(())$ for worst case running time of that algorithm?  Is this question statement better?

Comment: as I've mentioned upper bound can't be always that tight, if you prove that finding worst-case $O(f(n))$ implies that it is also $\Omega(f(n))$ it would be correct, but it isn't as I gave you counter-example. but the question you asked isn't well formulated like that, so I would suggest you edit the question and ask exactly that question.

Comment: reframed the question.